# .htaccess requires me to exit one directory more

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have got these files `index.php` and `user.php` and this htacess
`RewriteRule users/([^/]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [L,QSA]` now this changes my website to `domain.com/users/username` and if i have a file in the same directory as user.php it requires me to add `../` because it thinks that `users` is a folder name.For example

```
<script src="js/user.js"></script>
```

becomes

```
<script src="../js/user.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try `<script src="/js/user.js"></script>`

Comment: @Jon but then it goes back to root,but i need it in `Centill` folder